# Ggplot2 crashes when using fill aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am trying to create a plot using the fill aesthetics argument. When I am ready to print the plot, the session crashes. This is my session info

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.3 (Ootpa)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/libopenblas-r0.3.3.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] forcats_0.5.1   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.5     purrr_0.3.4
[5] readr_1.4.0     tidyr_1.1.3     tibble_3.1.0    ggplot2_3.3.3
[9] tidyverse_1.3.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.6        cellranger_1.1.0  pillar_1.5.1      compiler_4.0.3
 [5] dbplyr_2.1.0      tools_4.0.3       viridisLite_0.3.0 jsonlite_1.7.2
 [9] lubridate_1.7.10  lifecycle_1.0.0   gtable_0.3.0      pkgconfig_2.0.3
[13] rlang_0.4.10      reprex_1.0.0      cli_2.3.1         rstudioapi_0.13
[17] DBI_1.1.1         haven_2.3.1       withr_2.4.1       xml2_1.3.2
[21] httr_1.4.2        fs_1.5.0          generics_0.1.0    vctrs_0.3.6
[25] hms_1.0.0         grid_4.0.3        tidyselect_1.1.0  glue_1.4.2
[29] R6_2.5.0          fansi_0.4.2       readxl_1.3.1      modelr_0.1.8
[33] magrittr_2.0.1    ps_1.6.0          backports_1.2.1   scales_1.1.1
[37] ellipsis_0.3.1    rvest_0.3.6       assertthat_0.2.1  colorspace_2.0-0
[41] labeling_0.4.2    utf8_1.2.1        stringi_1.5.3     munsell_0.5.0
[45] broom_0.7.5       crayon_1.4.1
```

I used the example diamonds dataset to reproduce my error. If I save the data as a CSV first I can use the color and fill arguments, but when using the data without saving it first to a CSV the R session crashes.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(price, fill = cut)) +
geom_density()
```

This is the traceback of the error

```
 *** caught illegal operation ***
address 0x7f1db9212574, cause 'illegal operand'

Traceback:
 1: solve.default(M)
 2: solve(M)
 3: which(test)
 4: .ifelse(x <= 0.0031308, 12.92 * x, 1.055 * x %^% (1/2.4) - 0.055)
 5: ungamma(xyz %*% solve(M))
 6: to$fromXYZ(xyz, to.ref.white)
 7: convertColor(cbind(palette[[1L]](x), palette[[2L]](x), palette[[3L]](x),     if (alpha) palette[[4L]](x)), from = "Lab", to = "sRGB")
 8: pmin(rgb, 1)
 9: pmax(pmin(rgb, 1), 0)
10: roundcolor(convertColor(cbind(palette[[1L]](x), palette[[2L]](x),     palette[[3L]](x), if (alpha) palette[[4L]](x)), from = "Lab",     to = "sRGB"))
11: fn_cols(seq(begin, end, length.out = n))
12: viridisLite::viridis(n, alpha, begin, end, direction, option)
13: f(...)
14: self$palette(n)
15: f(..., self = self)
16: self$map(df[[j]])
17: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
18: lapply(aesthetics, function(j) self$map(df[[j]]))
19: f(..., self = self)
20: scale$map_df(df = df)
21: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
22: lapply(scales$scales, function(scale) scale$map_df(df = df))
23: unlist(lapply(scales$scales, function(scale) scale$map_df(df = df)),     recursive = FALSE)
24: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
25: lapply(data, scales_map_df, scales = npscales)
26: ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
27: ggplot_build(x)
28: print.ggplot(x)
29: (function (x, ...) UseMethod("print"))(x)
```

I updated all ggplot2 dependencies but that did not solve the problem. Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: That is odd. My initial guess is hardware memory problems or CPU instability. Are you running in RStudio, and if so, can you test from command line. There is a command line option `R  --vanilla` that loads a clean R environment.

Comment: Thanks! This error happens when I use RStudio and the command line. It might be as you suggested something to do with the hardware.

Comment: `memtest86+` is a good way to check RAM.  https://access.redhat.com/solutions/15693 You might need a system administrator, and this might also be a dead-end. Perhaps a reboot will help. I wonder if there are other symptoms.

Comment: Does a variation of the fill trigger? `ggplot(diamonds)+geom_boxplot(aes(price, fill = clarity))`

Comment: The variations `ggplot(diamonds) + geom_point(aes(carat,price,color = color))` or `ggplot(diamonds)+geom_boxplot(aes(price, fill = clarity))` also cause the same problem. I will talk to my system administrator to check the ram. Thanks!